# FFmpeg can't read a video stream, but VLC reads it fine

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, vlc

I have a video stream that I can access using VLC, but can't access with ffmpeg. This used to work before I moved onto using a new computer (but with same camera).

This is the ffprobe command (made up IP addr):

`ffprobe -hide_banner -rtsp_transport tcp "rtsp://root:pass@12.34.567.890:80/axis-media/media.amp?event=on&eventtopic=onvif:VideoSource/MotionAlarm/."`

It returns

```
rtsp://root:pass@12.34.567.890:80/axis-media/media.amp: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I've not found very much on this problem:

- I've tried turning it off and on again
- I looked through [this](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion/issues/946) github issue but there were no solutions
- I know it supports TCP since it's the same command as when it worked last time.

Any ideas how I can get ffmpeg to read the stream?

Edit: Output of -report below, I'm afraid it's not very helpful:

```
ffprobe started on 2022-05-21 at 06:27:54
Report written to "ffprobe-20220521-062754.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffprobe -hide_banner -report -rtsp_transport tcp 
"rtsp://root:pass@IPADDR:80/axis-media/media.amp? 
event=on&eventtopic=onvif:VideoSource/MotionAlarm/."
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Address IPADDR port 80
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Address IPADDR port 80
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Starting connection attempt to IPADDR port 80
[tcp @ 0000023967a2f8c0] Successfully connected to IPADDR port 80
rtsp://root:pass@IPADDR:80/axis-media/media.amp?event=on&eventtopic=onvif:VideoSource/MotionAlarm/.: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Added the output of -report, it confirms that it can connect to the address, doesn't shed much light on the invalid data. So frustrating that VLC can read it just fine.

Comment: any update? :( I got stuck here too